# Side-by-side divs in tabbed layout overlap on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

On the following page, the side-by-side content in the "PORTFOLIO ATTRIBUTES" tab at the bottom of the page renders just fine on desktop browsers, but when you view the chart side-by-side with the table on a mobile browser, they end up overlapping and one item gets cut off:

http://www.realitysharesadvisors.com/indexes/divcon-leaders/

Any suggestions on how to keep them side-by-side and responsive on mobile-sized browser windows as well?  The chart and table at the top of the page seem to render just fine and stay side-by-side on mobile browsers.  Thanks.

Code is below:

```
<div id="attributes" class="tab-pane fade"><div style="width:65%;display:inline-block"><iframe src="/charts/DIVCONleaderspie.htm" width="100%" height="450px" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"></iframe></div><div style="width:33%;float:right"><table style="width:100%;font-size:14px;padding:0px"><thead style="text-align:left"><tr><th style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#005580" scope="col">TOP 10 HOLDINGS</th><th style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#005580" scope="col">WEIGHT<sup>*</sup></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Starbucks Corp.</td><td>5.16%</td></tr><tr><td>Yum! Brands, Inc.</td><td>4.63%</td></tr><tr><td>Celanese Corp.</td><td>4.37%</td></tr><tr><td>Nike Inc.</td><td>4.11%</td></tr><tr><td>Moody's Corp.</td><td>4.04%</td></tr><tr><td>CR Bard Inc.</td><td>3.88%</td></tr><tr><td>CVS Health Corp.</td><td>3.86%</td></tr><tr><td>Wabtec Corp.</td><td>3.80%</td></tr><tr><td>Visa Inc.</td><td>3.73%</td></tr><tr><td>Polaris Industries Inc.</td><td>3.68%</td></tr></tbody></table></div><br /></div>
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific and add your code?

Comment: Hi @AdamBuchananSmith, I added the specific code.  The two divs (one is 65% width and one is 33% width) end up overlapping when you view them on a mobile browser, so the table ends up on top of the interactive chart iframe.  It displays just fine on a desktop browser and larger windows.

Answer (score 0):

you probably shouldn't be using inline styles here, but thats a whole different discussion. in a mobile display you probably want these columns to expand to 100% using

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .my-element {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

or even better since you are using bootstrap, you could wrap both divs in a .row div and then assign them a class of col-md-6 and elimnate your inline width styles

Comment: Thank you Destination Designs. Where you have "my-element", would that be replaced with whatever class the tabbed content is within?  Or do I literally use "my-element"?

Comment: yep and max-width would be where ever you want the breakpoint to be for a mobile display